# Installing Ruby on Rails from Source - cannot load such file -- openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, ruby-on-rails-4

I am on a Mac, using Lion. I am configuring my system for Ruby on Rails development but I ran into some issues. Instead of using brew or other shortcuts I want to configure Ruby on Rails from source. So, here is what I did.

**Installed Ruby 2.0**

- Downloaded the source from the Ruby website
- Compiled it by running the following code:

  ./configure --prefix=/Users/user/Applications/ruby2

  make

  make install
- And made sure the $PATH file is updated to point to /Users/user/Applications/ruby2/bin

So, I am able to call `ruby -v` or if I do `which ruby` it does point to my custom compiled version of Ruby.

**Installed Node.js**

- Downloaded the source from the main website
- Compiled it by running the following code:

  ./configure --prefix=/Users/user/Applications/nodejs

  make

  make install
- And made sure the $PATH file is updated to point to /Users/user/Applications/nodejs/bin

So, I am able to call `node -v` or if I do `which node` it does point to my custom compiled version of Ruby.

I also did the same steps for openssl and it is also accessible from the console or if I do `which openssl` it points to `/Users/user/Application/openssl/bin`

But still when I execute `gem install rails` I still get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea why?

**System Specs**

- Mac Lion 10.8.4
- OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
- ruby 2.0.0p291
- Nodejs v0.10.15

Comment: OS X has pre-installed version of `openssl` so may be try using that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by doing the following. The main problem was the step I followed to compile openssl itself.

Since I am on a 64 bit machine, I had to configure openssl by running the following command first

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/user/Applications/openssl darwin64-x86_64-cc
./make
./make install
```

And recompile ruby as such

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/user/Applications/ruby2 --with-openssl-dir=/Users/user/Applications/openssl
./make
./make install
```

Note: Even though while compiling ruby it might say... the option --with-openssl-dir is not valid or does not exist, ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

I had very bad time with this ERROR.
Finally i done with it. There is only Once solution either you are with RVM or without RVM.

**Make sure you have installed OpenSSL first BEFORE installing ruby.**

First you should find where Ruby is:

```
whereis ruby
```

will list all the places where it exists on your system, then you can remove all them explicitly. Or you can use something like this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

THEN

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev curl git-core python-software-properties libpq-dev nodejs

apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev
cd /tmp
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.0.0-p247/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This answer was probably down voted at least in part because it assumes a Debian-based version of Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) when the OP says they are trying to do this on a Mac.